# Translating Puppet to Ansible

Tags: ansible, task, puppet, roles

This is the puppet code managing a [service](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/service.html):

```
class fred::service {

service { 'bob':
        enable => true,
        ensure => 'running',
        require => Package['bob-5.4']
    }
}
```

My translation in Ansible role

```
---
- name: check bob
    service:
    name: bob
    enabled: true
    state: running
    package:
    name: bob-5.4
    state: present
```

My question is:

1. Is the translation correct?
2. I am told package comes before service?
3. Do I require `package:`

Comment: That'll be two tasks in Ansible, in the opposite order (package installation first)

Answer (score 2):

The order is incorrect. You should first attempt to install the package. It will automatically skip this (resulting in `ok`) if the package is already present.

When checking if the service is running, `state: running` is not valid in Ansible, it should be `state: started`.

```
- name: Install package
  apt:
    name: bob-5.4
    state: present

- name: Check if service is running
  service:
    name: bob
    state: started
    enabled: yes
```

Depending on what you install the package with, this may require a little modification (`package` or `yum` instead of `apt` for example).

- [Reference for `apt` in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html)
- [Reference for `package` in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html)
- [Reference for `yum` in Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html)